# If $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$, $\lim f(x) \leq \lim g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $a$ be a limit point of $X$. Let $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $f(x) < g(x), \forall x \in X$, and $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ and give an example for which the limits are equal.

I'm stuck in epsilon-delta stuff (of which I have a pretty poor grasp anyway). How can I use the epsilon-delta definition of a limit to prove the above? Does continuity have anything to do with it?

Comment: Even if you have a poor grasp, you can tell us how your started. People won't laugh at you or ridicule you : we are here to help you, so you must do the needful. Do you know the definitions?

Comment: Well there's the problem: I know the definitions, I just don't know where to start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Setting $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$, this amounts to showing that if $h(x)>0$ for all $x$, then $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}h(x)\ge 0$.

Comment: What allows us to assume that $f(x)>0$ for all x?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo – I meant $h(x)$. I've fixed it.

Comment: Ok thank you. But again, what if $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are both negative?

Comment: The difference of two negative numbers can be positive

Comment: Their difference is still positive with your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, let's assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = L$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = M$ and $f(x) < g(x)$.

We are going to prove that $L\leq M$.

According to the definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there are $\delta_{1} > 0$ and $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1} \Rightarrow 
|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon\\\\
0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2} \Rightarrow |g(x) - M| < \varepsilon
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow L - \varepsilon < f(x) < g(x) < M + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

If we assume that $L > M$, for $\displaystyle\varepsilon = \frac{L - M}{3}$, there is a $\delta = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
M - L + 2\epsilon = M - L + \frac{2(L-M)}{3} = \frac{M - L}{3} > 0 \Longrightarrow M > L
\end{align*}
which contradicts our assumption. Thus $M\geq L$, and we are done.